# Spark 2.0.2 PySpark failing to Import collect_list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a `DataFrame` of the form:

```
+--------------+------------+----+
|             s|variant_hash|call|
+--------------+------------+----+
|C1046::HG02024|    83779208|   0|
|C1046::HG02025|    83779208|   1|
|C1046::HG02026|    83779208|   0|
|C1047::HG00731|    83779208|   0|
|C1047::HG00732|    83779208|   1
              ...
```

I was hoping to leverage `collect_list()` to transform it into:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                   s|                       feature_vector|
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+
|      C1046::HG02024|[(83779208,   0), (68471259,   2)...]|
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Where the feature vector column is a list of tuples of the form `(variant_hash, call)`. I was planning on leveraging `groupBy` and `agg(collect_list())` to accomplish this result, but am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ba6a891c-529b-4c75-a76f-8ab20f4377ba/ml_on_vds.py", line 43, in <module>
    vector_df = svc_df.groupBy('s').agg(func.collect_list(('variant_hash', 'call')))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 39, in _
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method collect_list([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The below code shows my imports. I didn't think it was necessary to import `HiveContext` and `enableHiveSupport` in 2.0.2, but I had hoped doing so would resolve the issue. Sadly, no luck. Does anyone have any recommendations to resolve this import issue?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, hash, collect_list
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from hail import *
# Initialize the SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("PopulationGenomics")
        .config("spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes", "1099511627776")
        .config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "1099511627776")
        .config("spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,is.hail.io.compress.BGzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate())
```

I am attempting run this code on a gcloud dataproc cluster.

Answer (score 1):

so it throws error at this line -

```
vector_df = svc_df.groupBy('s').agg(func.collect_list(('variant_hash', 'call')))
```

you are calling `collect_list` as `func.collect_list` 
but you are importing functions as -

`from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, hash, collect_list`

**may be you meant to import functions as 'func' like**

`from pyspark.sql import functions as func`,

Comment: Appreciate the response Pushkr. Went ahead and made that correction but am still receiving the same error message. When looking at my IDE (not connected to my Spark cluster, but includes should match), it doesn't appear that `collect_list` is included in `pyspark.sql.functions`...

Comment: Can you do a simple test in spark CLI to check if you are able to import any sql functions and run them?

Comment: Was able to import and run `hash` and `udf` from the functions library.

Comment: @mongolol - Did you find a solution? Are you able to import collect_list()?

Comment: @outlier123 Sadly we've since moved on from 2.0.2 and aren't encountering this issue any more.